# Remove legend key in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, legend

I want to show a legend text but without a key (the rectangular box or line that appears by default).

```
plt.hist(x, label = 'something')
```

[image]

I don't want the box next to the legend "something". How to remove it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, you may decide not to create a legend at all and instead put some label in to corner of the plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.random.normal(size=160)
plt.hist(x)

plt.text(0.95,0.95, 'something', ha="right", va="top", transform=plt.gca().transAxes)
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you already created the legend and want to remove it, you can do so by

```
plt.gca().get_legend().remove()
```

and then add the text instead.

If this is not an option, you may set the legend handle invisible like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.random.normal(size=160)
plt.hist(x, label = 'something')

plt.legend()

leg = plt.gca().get_legend()
leg.legendHandles[0].set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I knew text but thought that this could be done in matplotlib. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Following the matplotlib [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html), you can change the `handlelength` and `handletextpad` parameters to remove the handle and the space behind the label text

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.random.normal(size=160)
plt.hist(x, label = 'something')
plt.legend(handlelength=0, handletextpad=0, loc='upper right')

plt.show()
```

[image]