# python matplotlib custom legend

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, legend

I am using python to stream and plot some sensor data from an arduino to my pc.
I want the graph to have a legend with some values (that I also stream from my serial connection of course) but in all examples I found there was a big space at the left side of the legend.

How can I remove it? (Or get the same output using something else)

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import spline
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

# Local variables
x = []
y = []

# Open the data file for reading lines
datafile = open('./plotfiles/forceplot.txt', 'r')
sepfile = datafile.read().split('\n')
datafile.close()

# Create a canvas to place the subgraphs
canvas = plt.figure()
rect = canvas.patch
rect.set_facecolor('white')

# Iterate through the lines and parse them
for datapair in sepfile:
    if datapair:
        xypair = datapair.split(',')
        x.append(int(xypair[0]))
        y.append(int(xypair[1]))

x_sm = np.array(x)
y_sm = np.array(y)

x_smooth = np.linspace(x_sm.min(), x_sm.max(), 200)
y_smooth = spline(x, y, x_smooth)

# Define the matrix of 1x1 to place subplots
# Placing the plot1 on 1x1 matrix, at pos 1
sp1 = canvas.add_subplot(1,1,1)
#sp1.plot(x, y, 'red', linewidth=2)
sp1.plot(x_smooth, y_smooth, 'red', linewidth=1)

# Colorcode the tick tabs 
sp1.tick_params(axis='x', colors='red')
sp1.tick_params(axis='y', colors='red')

# Colorcode the spine of the graph
sp1.spines['bottom'].set_color('r')
sp1.spines['top'].set_color('r')
sp1.spines['left'].set_color('r')
sp1.spines['right'].set_color('r')

# Put the title and labels
sp1.set_title('matplotlib example 1', color='red')
sp1.set_xlabel('matplot x label', color='red')
sp1.set_ylabel('matplot y label', color='red')

# Show the plot/image
time = 'time: 00:23'
s = 3
sh = "success hits: "+str(s)
legend_dict = { sh: sh, 'total hits' : '5', time : time}
patchList=[]
for key in legend_dict:
    data_key = mpatches.Patch(color='None', label=key)
    patchList.append(data_key)

plt.legend(handles=patchList)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.grid(alpha=0.8)
plt.savefig("example6.eps")
plt.show()
```

And this is the output:

[image]

Comment: [Write the text instead of creating a legend?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44603661/8881141)

Comment: @Mr.T Ok but how can I autoscale the coordinates of the text?

Answer (score 1):

Since the color is None, it displays empty space. If you use text:

text(x, y,'time: 00:23\nsuccess hits: 3\ntotal hits: 5', horizontalalignment='center',
     verticalalignment='center')

Comment: Your x and y would be 1 and 1 as you want it on top right.

Comment: So, after reading my comment you fundamentally changed your answer and copied the suggestion from the linked answer? This is not how SO is supposed to work.

Comment: I did change my answer as I had did not read his complete code, but I never referred to your link. I got that text from my previous codes.

Comment: @Srikar T And what can I do for autoscale? My figure has autoscale and when the graph increases in x axe or the figure window gets changed my text is hidden or get's close to the middle of the graph

Comment: Try using anchored text instead of the normal one. From mpl_toolkits use the AnchoredText.

`txt = AnchoredText("YOUR TEXT",loc=1),
ax.add_artist(txt)`