# How to remove the lines/markers on a matplotlib legend?

Tags: matplotlib, legend, legend-properties

By default when I call matplotlib `legend` the output is:

[image: default legend matplotlib]

But in my case, I want the text to have the color of the line and I want to remove the line of the legend.

**Desired outcome**:

[image]

How can I do this?

**Partial sucess**

My searches only allowed me to get the [text with the correct colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18909696/how-to-change-the-text-colour-of-font-in-legend)

[image]

[and puting those lines transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603480/remove-legend-key-in-matplotlib)

[image]

But there is still space on the legend box.

Is there a way to make this?

Answer (score 5):

I ended up finding the answer:

When you call the legend add these properties

```
ax.legend(handlelength=0, handletextpad=0)
```

Those lines are called handles, and you set their length to 0 and with no pad between them and the text.

Comment: That works visually, but actually there is still an object there and some renders display the object